# Searching in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, binary-search-tree

This code to search a value in a Binary Search Tree is not working completely.

The struct node has int data and struct *lc,*rc as its members.

Here `*r` is a global variable of type struct node.

```
struct node * searchbt(struct node*bn,int x)

{   if(bn==NULL)

    {printf("Element not found.\n");}

    if(bn->data==x) {printf("Element found.\n"); r=bn; return r;}

    if(bn->data<x)  {searchbt((bn->lc),x);}

    else {searchbt((bn->rc),x);}
}
```

This code to search compiles but fails at run time to search any element of a functioning BST.The program is expected to return a pointer to the found node.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: trying to search a value in a Given Binary Search Tree.

Comment: so manu -ve votes........no answers though.

Comment: Yup.  Read the community rules.

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble ?

Comment: The code doesn't work.i am asking what are the errors possible here?

Comment: You should describe in detail the problem you are experimenting. Does it compile? If not, what errors are you getting? If it compiles, can you run it? Does it stop at runtime with an error? Does it gives strange results? If yes, provide an example of what it gives and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct node * searchbt(struct node*bn,int x)

{   if(bn==NULL)

    {printf("Element not found.\n"); return bn;} //return bn

    if(bn->data==x) {printf("Element found.\n"); return bn;} //Just return bn

    if(bn->data<x)  {return searchbt((bn->lc),x);} // <- Add return 

    else { return searchbt((bn->rc),x);} //<- Add return
}
```

Comment: is returning r wrong? also bn is a local variable it would get destroyed as control passes from the block.I am confused here.Plz answer.

Comment: @RafedNole what makes you think so ? I suggest you to read a good C book. And check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_science%29#Parameters_and_arguments).
Also, if I'm correct you already have your answer.